# How to pass one class to another in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, oop

I have the following class UserRepo:

```
import User from './UserModel'
export default class UserRepo { 
   async createUser(user: {name: string}): Promise<User>{
       const user = new User(user);
       return await user.save()
  }
}
```

I want to export this class and bind it in another class in constructor, so I can have access to this method **createUser** (and the whole instance of the class UserRepo) in another class. For example this.UserRepo.createUser({name: "Bob"});

Pseudocode of my thoughts on the new class:

```
import User from './UserModel'
import UserRepo from './UserRepo';

interface IUserImplementation {
    insertUser(user: {name: string}): Promise<User>
}

export default class UserImplementation implements IUserImplementation {
    constructor(UserRepo) {
        this.userRepo = new UserRepo();
    }
    
    async insertUser(user: {name: string}){
        const data = await this.userRepo.createUser(user);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You might be looking to implement a [dependency injection](https://nehalist.io/dependency-injection-in-typescript/) pattern.

recommended:

```
export default class UserImplementation implements IUserImplementation {
    constructor(UserRepo: UserRepo) { // have the user create the UserRepo instance
        this.userRepo = UserRepo;
    }
    
    async insertUser(user: {name: string}){
        const data = await this.userRepo.createUser(user);
    }
}
```

You can also do:

```
export default class UserImplementation implements IUserImplementation {
    constructor() { // nothing
        this.userRepo = new UserRepo(); // create instance in constructor
    }
    
    async insertUser(user: {name: string}){
        const data = await this.userRepo.createUser(user);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @saulmaldonado, thanks for the clarification, I am looking for dependency injection. However, I am still confused with the recommended approach. Should I have another file where I will create an instance of the UserImplementation class? Something like: 
const urepo = new UserRepo();
const uimplementation = new UserImplementation(urepo)?

Comment: Yes, that is right! This allows you to create a `UserRepo`, make any additions or changes to its state (a good example of this can be a db connection, or db name), and pass it into `UserImplementation` to use. If you need to, you can also pass the same `UserRepo` instance into other classes and use it as a global service for your application